# Ubuntu 18.04 upgarde error

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I am getting the following error while upgrading packages.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click : Depends: python3-click-package (= 0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
         Recommends: click-apparmor but it is not installable
 libunity-scopes1.0 : Depends: libnet-cpp2 (>= 1.1.0+15.04.20150305) but it is not installable
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1) but 9.0.1-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And while running **apt --fix-broken install** I get the following error:

```
Removing click (0.4.46+17.10.20170607.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click_package as click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click_package'
dpkg: error processing package click (--remove):
 installed click package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Job for click-system-hooks.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status click-system-hooks.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Removing libunity-scopes1.0:amd64 (1.0.8+17.04.20170116-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click_package as click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click_package'
dpkg: error processing package libunity-scopes1.0:amd64 (--remove):
 installed libunity-scopes1.0:amd64 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 click
 libunity-scopes1.0:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: See `systemctl status click-system-hooks.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`What does it say?

Comment: ● click-system-hooks.service - Run Click system-level hooks
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/click-system-hooks.service; enabled; vend
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-06-28 15:42:24 IST; 12min a
     Docs: man:click(1)
  Process: 883 ExecStart=/usr/bin/click hook run-system (code=exited, status=1/F
 Main PID: 883 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: Starting Run Click system-level hooks...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <mod
   import click_package as click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cli
 click-system-hooks.service: Main process 
click-system-hooks.service: Failed with r
 Failed to start Run Click system-level ho